# Symfony is not generating a Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I can't generate a Bundle with Symfony. Indeed, I have even try to solve my probleme with a solution give on StackOverflow, but it's always doesn't work.

[image: Console Error]

[image: localhost Error]

[image: The solution that doesn't work]

Comment: Please don't post your code and the error messages as an image, but as formatted text. That makes it so much easier to copy it.

Comment: Please check on that `stPlatformBundle` class of yours  to make sure it was generated ok. In my books, it feels bad for class name to begin with lower letter :)

Comment: Look at the last two lines in your error message.  Pretty much tells you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your anwsers but my problem is not solved, I've tried to do that:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/",
        "DF\\TestBundle\\": "src/DF/TestBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

There is always this error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DFTestBundle" from namespace "DF\TestBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace? in C:\wamp64\www\symfonyTest\app\AppKernel.php:20
```

Comment: As a rule you should use the edit button under your question to add this sort of information.  Adding it as an answer implies that the question is answered.  With that out of the way, look closely at "src/" vs "src/DF/TestBundle" Can you spot the difference?  and be sure to run "composer dumpautoload" after making changes to composer.json